# Ember JSON API Adapter - customise request URL using dynamic param

Tags: ember-data

When the action below is called in a route, the  default the Ember JSON API Adapter will send a `PATCH` request to `${HOST}/${NAMESPACE}/${MODEL}/${ID}`.

```js
saveChanges: function(record) {
  return record.save();
},
```

I would like to be able to send a single PATCH request to `${HOST}/${NAMESPACE}/${MODEL}/************/${ID}` where the value of `************` can be passed to the action as a dynamic parameter when calling `record.save()`.

Is there any way to do this using the JSONAPI adapter, or do I have to just use a vanilla AJAX request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize your application- or model-adapter

```
ember generate adapter application
```

or

```
ember generate adapter model-name
```

**app/adapters/application.js or app/adapters/model-name.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api',

  urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    let originalUpdateURL = this._super(...arguments);

    let { adapterOptions } = snapshot;
    if (adapterOptions && adapterOptions.customString) {
      let modelPath = this.pathForType(modelName);
      return originalUpdateURL.replace(`/${modelPath}/`, `/${modelPath}/${adapterOptions.customString}/`);
    }
    return originalUpdateURL;
  }

});
```

after that you can call save-method of your model with adapterOptions passed:

```
this.get('model').save({
  adapterOptions: { customString: 'hello-world' }
});
```

after that your patchURL will look like:
/api/your-model/hello-world/1